# Why would I get a 503 error when accessing a .php file?

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-503

I have a website that makes extensive use of php. I had everything running fine until I needed to call a Python script using exec() in php.

After researching the problem I decided what I really needed, for a variety of reasons, was php-fpm. I have installed php-fpm, I believe. But when I attempt to use my browser to reach /phpinfo.php I get a 503 error.

I can access any .html file on the site using my browser, but attempting to load any .php file results in a 503 error.

Since I can access the .html fees I know that Apache is working, but I can't rule out this being a problem between php and Apace on the Apache side.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: This can have a million different reasons, none of which we can debug for you (the prime candidate is socket permissions). You will have to look through both the apache and php-fpm logs to figure out what's going on. Being able to access HTML files is irrelevant, because it doesn't involve PHP.

Comment: Wthile the previous comment is correct, the starting points

Does the Apache process have the rights to read the php files.
Does .htaccess allows php files to be loaded

Comment: The php files are in the same directory as the html files, so I am reasonably certain that Apache has the rights to read the php files.

The php files were working until I installed php-fpm, so unless the installation process altered the .htaccess file, I doubt that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Linux was not recognizing the php.ini file properly.

This was the last straw. I switched everything to Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS. Everything is working now.